# convert class.phpmailer.php html email to class.smtp.php

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I spent the last 2 days getting a web form to send to outside domains using an internal exchange server with phpmailer.

Unfortunately now, the syntax is different and my old code doesn't work.

Has anyone used smtp.php class to send html emails?

Old code, can only send internally:

```
require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php"; 

$mail = new PHPMailer();  
$mail->IsSMTP();              
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;  
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;       
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;      
$mail->Host = "10.10.10.10";
$mail->Port = 25;  


$mail->From = "user@company.com";
$mail->FromName = "user";
$mail->SetFrom("user@company.com", "user);


$mail->Subject = $_POST['company'].": New MFD(s) (Time Sensitive)"; 

$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('trans2.png', 'logo', 'trans2.png ');

$mail->AddAttachment("docs/install.xlsx"); 
$mail->MsgHTML($message1.$message2.$message3);


$mail->AddAddress($_POST['emailid'], ""); 
$mail->AddCC("user@company.com");
$result = $mail->Send();    
$message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';      
unset($mail);

}
```

new code, which works with an exchange server sending to outside domains:

```
require("smtp.php");
require("sasl.php");

$from="user@company.com"; $sender_line=__LINE__;
$to="person@company.com";  $recipient_line=__LINE__;

if(strlen($from)==0)
    die("Please set the messages sender address in line ".$sender_line." of the script ".basename(__FILE__)."\n");
if(strlen($to)==0)
    die("Please set the messages recipient address in line ".$recipient_line." of the script ".basename(__FILE__)."\n");

$smtp=new smtp_class;

$smtp->host_name="mailserver"; /
$smtp->host_port=587;  
$smtp->ssl=0;  

$smtp->start_tls=1; 
$smtp->localhost="localhost";  
$smtp->direct_delivery=0;   
$smtp->timeout=10;  
$smtp->data_timeout=0;
$smtp->debug=1;  
$smtp->html_debug=1; 
$smtp->pop3_auth_host=""; 
$smtp->user="user"; 
$smtp->realm="myrealm";   
$smtp->password="mywonderfulpassword";             
$smtp->workstation="workstationname";      
$smtp->authentication_mechanism="NTLM"; 

if($smtp->direct_delivery)
{
    if(!function_exists("GetMXRR"))
    {

        $_NAMESERVERS=array();
        include("getmxrr.php");
    }

    else
    {
        $_NAMESERVERS=array();
        if(count($_NAMESERVERS)==0)
            Unset($_NAMESERVERS);
        include("rrcompat.php");
        $smtp->getmxrr="_getmxrr";
    }

}

if($smtp->SendMessage(
    $from,
    array(
        $to
    ),
    array(
        "From: $from",
        "To: $to",
        "Subject: Testing Manuel Lemos' SMTP class",
        "Date: ".strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
    ),
    "Hello $to,\n\nIt is just to let you know that your SMTP class is working just fine.\n\nBye.\n"))
    echo "Message sent to $to OK.\n";
else
    echo "Could not send the message to $to.\nError: ".$smtp->error."\n";
```

How do i send html emails and add attachments?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is PHPMailer not working for you ? What do you mean by convert to class.smtp.php? Why do you need to convert it ?

Comment: Additionally, do you have error reporting turned on for your PHP code ? Are there any errors that you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Disregard, I was able to get the phpmailer to work with my exchange server

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();  

// Set up SMTP  
$mail->IsSMTP();               
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;       
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';     
$mail->Host = "exchangeserver.com";
$mail->Port = 587;  



$mail->Username   = $_POST['emailusername'] ; 
$mail->Password   = $_POST['emailpassword'] ;
```